# $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$, prove that $ (\int_0^1 f(x)dx)^2 \leq \frac {1} {12} \int_0^1 (f'(x))^2 dx $

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)$ is a real function continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$. $f(0) = f(1) = 0$

Prove that 
$$
\left(\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{dx}\right)^2 \leq \frac {1} {12} \int_0^1 (f'(x))^2 \mathrm{dx}
$$

Comment: Oh sorry I omitted a condition

Comment: It's old problem:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018659/how-prove-this-inequality-left-int-01fxdx-right2-le-frac112-int?rq=1

Comment: (math110) [+1], Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to solve this

Comment: How do I mark this as duplicate then??

Comment: Another way to do this is by Fourier series.