# Inequality $(\int_0^1 |f|)^2 \leq \frac{1}{12}\int_0^1 {f'}^2$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Assume that $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function with $f'$ square integrable *(if that's too weak or unpractical, assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable)* such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Is it the case that
$$
 \left(\int_0^1 |f|\right)^2 \leq \frac{1}{12}\int_0^1 {f'}^2
$$
? It holds for the functions $f$ I have tried (e.g., the obvious $f(x)=x(1-x)$, and things like $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$). Moreover, it is not difficult to see that $1/12$ is the best one can hope for, since it's achieved for $f(x)=x(1-x)$.

It seems to reek of Cauchy-Schwarz and/or integration by parts, but I can't see how to prove it. It feels I am one simple trick short.

Comment: Now that the website is suggesting similar questions (i.e., after posting my question), it looks like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018659/how-prove-this-inequality-left-int-01fxdx-right2-le-frac112-int) is really similar. I'm going to check if the proof allows for the absolute value.

Comment: Not sure. The answers to the (similar, but different) question I just linked rely on the fact that $$\int_0^1 f'(x)(x-1/2)dx = -\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$ (since $f(0)-f(1)=0$) by IPP; which is not obvious at all to me when considering   $\int_0^1 |f'(x)(x-1/2)|dx$.

Comment: If $f$ satisfies your assumptions, then so does $|f|$, with derivative $\frac{d}{dx} |f(x)| = f'(x) 1_{f(x) >0} - f'(x) 1_{f(x) <0}$, which implies $\Big|\frac{d}{dx} |f| \Big| \leq |f'|$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Sorry to be daft, but how is $|f|$ differentiable at the points where $f$ cancels?

Comment: does not seem to hold with $f(x) =e ^{x(1-x)}$ !

Comment: @Ahmad $f(0)=f(1)=0$?

Comment: I was a little imprecise. If $f$ is in $W^{1,2}$, then so is $|f|$. For Details see e.g. Theorem 1.26 here: https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix a $c \in (0,1)$. For $0 \leq t\leq c$, since $f(0) =0$ we have
$$|f(t)| = |\int_0^t f'(s) ds|\leq \int_0^t |f'(s)| ds.$$
Therefore, by Fubini theorem, we have
$$ \int_0^c |f(t)| dt \leq \int_0^c \int_0^t |f'(s)| ds dt = \int_0^c |f'(s)| (c-s) ds.$$
Similarly, we get
$$ \int_c^1 |f(t)| dt \leq \int_c^1 |f'(s)| (s-c) ds.$$
Hence, by summing two inequalities, we obtain
$$\int_0^1 |f(t)| dt \leq \int_0^1 |f'(s)| |c -s| ds.$$
Applying Cauchy-Schwartz, we have
$$(\int_0^1 |f(t)| dt)^2 \leq (\int_0^1 f'(s)^2 ds )(\int_0^1(c-s)^2 ds) =(c^2 -c + \frac13) \int_0^1 f'(s)^2 ds,$$
for any $c\in (0,1)$. Since $c^2-c + \frac13 \geq \frac1{12}$ for any $c\in (0,1)$ and attains at $c = \frac12$. By taking $c =\frac12$, we get the desired inequality.

Comment: Thank you! So essentially, the key here is to replace IPP which ensures that $$\left\lvert\int_0^1 f(x)dx \right\rvert = \left\rvert \int_0^1 f(x)(x-1/2)dx\right\rvert$$ by a triangle inequality+Fubini applied to both halves to get that 
$$\int_0^1 \left\lvert f(x) \right\rvert dx \leq \int_0^1 \left\rvert f(x)(x-1/2)\right\rvert dx$$