# Integral Inequality $( \int_0^1{f(x)} \, dx)^2 \le \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 (f'(x))^2 \, dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuously differentiable function, and $f(\frac{1}{2})=0$. I'm trying to show
$$( \int_0^1{f(x)} \, dx)^2 \le \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 (f'(x))^2  \, dx $$
I tried using the mean value theorem but got nowhere.  Are there any hints? Thank you!

Comment: You may find [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018659/how-prove-this-inequality-left-int-01fxdx-right2-le-frac112-int?rq=1) useful, as it is similar in nature.

Comment: @cmk: Certainly similar, but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(x) = \int_{1 \over 2}^x f'(t)dt$ and Cauchy Schwartz gives
$|f(x)| \le \|f'\| \sqrt{|x-{1 \over 2}|}$.

Since $\int_0^1 \sqrt{|x-{1 \over 2}|}dx = {\sqrt{2} \over 3}$, we get
$(\int_0^1 f(x) dx)^2  \le (\int_0^1 |f(x)| dx)^2 \le {2 \over 9} \int_0^1 (f'(x))^2 dx$ with a little to spare :-).

Comment: It is the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Sorry, so $$f(x)^2 \leq \left( \int_{1/2}^x (f'(t))^2 \, {\rm d}t\right) \left( \int_{1/2}^x 1 \, {\rm d}t  \right) \, ?$$

Comment: Close. Apply Cauchy Schwartz to $\int f' \cdot 1_{[{1 \over 2},x]}$.

Comment: ? That's what I did, or what is wrong with my notation? Or is the integral $\int_{1/2}^x ...$ no vector space? Do I need to extent it to $\int_0^1 ...$ and introduce the indicator function?

Comment: Well, I would have $\int_0^1$ on the $f'$ integral.

Comment: So is $\int_{1/2}^x ...$ no vector space?

Comment: @Diger: I have no idea what your last comment means.